# Custom loss function and built-in function categorical crossentropy gave different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to understand how to use custom loss function with Keras.

Basically it's just MNIST hand-written digit multi-class classification problem.

I tried to train it, first attempt using `original_cce`, second attempt using `custom_cce` which the formula should be mathematically same in *literatures*.

Here is my cell:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam  # Import the Adam optimizer
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy

def custom_cce(y_true, y_pred):
    # # Ensure that y_pred is not a logit tensor
    epsilon = K.epsilon()
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)

    # Cast y_true to float32
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, 'float32')

    # Compute the cross-entropy loss
    loss = -K.sum(y_true * K.log(y_pred), axis=-1)

    return loss

# Define the input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(784,))  # 784 is the flattened image size (28x28)

# Define the hidden layer with 128 units and ReLU activation
hidden_layer = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_layer)

# Define the output layer with 10 units (for 10 digits) and softmax activation
output_layer = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(hidden_layer)

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

adam_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)  # Adjust the learning rate as needed

original_cce = CategoricalCrossentropy()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss=custom_cce, metrics=['accuracy']) # this gave me low accuracy
# model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss=original_cce, metrics=['accuracy']) # while this gave me accuracy about 0.9

# Print a summary of the model architecture
model.summary()

display(train_images_flat.shape, train_labels_encoded.shape)
```

Here is the output:

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_5 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784)]             0         
                                                                 
 dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 128)               100480    
                                                                 
 dense_9 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 101770 (397.54 KB)
Trainable params: 101770 (397.54 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________

(60000, 784)

(60000, 10)
```

Here is the last row of using custom_cce during training:

```
Epoch 10/10
375/375 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 10.8553 - accuracy: 0.3264 - val_loss: 10.5043 - val_accuracy: 0.3478
```

And here is the first row of using original_cce during training:

```
Epoch 1/10
365/375 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.2579 - accuracy: 0.7928
```

All setup remains same. But why it gave me different accuracy even though both of them are CCE? I feel there's something I need to setup in the custom loss function.

How do I define custom loss function that equivalent with built-in function of CategoricalCrossentropy that defined by Keras team?

Comment: compile the model with `loss = [custom_cce, original_cce]` then you can run and check whether the results for the two are different.